# CSS click span to show form and keep it open

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if it's possible to keep another element open upon clicking span or link. Here is an example of what I am trying to do, if you click on the + sign, the form display, but soon as i get off the span, the form goes away. http://jsfiddle.net/robx/68jmY/

I know it's possible with the help of JQuery, but is it possible to do without any javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/68jmY/3/

Something along these lines could work. Here is what I changed...

```
<span id="expand"><a href="#contact">+</a></span>
```

...

```
#contact:target { display: block; }
#expand a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `:target` pseudo-class: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-mimic-a-click-event-with-css/